# I would like to know how to get rid of the 0 bytes when recording with gstreamer

Tags: python-3.x, gstreamer

Please help.
I have gstremaer running in python, but the recording produces a 0 byte file.

The following is the source code
Please let me know if you find anything wrong.

class RecordVideoThread(threading.Thread):
def **init**(self):
super().**init**()

```
    self.is_recording = True
    self.is_stopped = False
    self.start_time = None
    self.end_time = None  

    Gst.init(sys.argv)
    self.pipeline = Gst.parse_launch(
        "v4l2src ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=1920,height=1080 ! tee name=t1 ! queue ! videorate  ! video/x-raw,framerate=60/1 ! "
        "vpuenc_h264 ! h264parse ! queue ! mux. alsasrc device=hw:1,1 ! tee name=t2 ! queue ! audioconvert ! "
        "queue ! audio/x-raw,rate=44100,channels=2,format=S16LE ! lamemp3enc ! queue ! mux. qtmux name=mux ! "
        "filesink location=/mnt/sd/output.mp4 sync=false t1. ! queue ! waylandsink t2. ! queue ! alsasink device=hw:0,0")

    

    self.loop = GLib.MainLoop()
    
    self.is_recording = True

def run(self):
    self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
    
    segment = Gst.Segment()
    segment.init(Gst.Format.TIME)
    segment.start = Gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE
    segment.stop = Gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE

    self.pipeline.send_event(Gst.Event.new_segment(segment))

    try:
        LEDController.turn_on_led(0x01)  
        self.loop.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        self.pipeline.send_event(Gst.Event.new_eos())  
        self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)

def stop(self):
   
    self.is_recording = False

  
    self.pipeline.send_event(Gst.Event.new_flush_start())
    self.pipeline.send_event(Gst.Event.new_flush_stop(True))
    
    self.pipeline.send_event(Gst.Event.new_eos())

    self.loop.quit()
    self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)  
    self.rename_video_file()
```